# ios 7 pin viewforannotation not showing up

Tags: ios, mkmapview, pins

I upgraded a perfectly working 6.1 app to Xcode 5/ios 7
that uses MKMapKit to show some pins on a mapview.

Now the annotation pins dont show up.  Ive made sure
my mapview delegate is correct and viewForAnnotation is being called.
Im also sure its title and subtitle are set, but now the pin just doesnt
display.  Anyone have any ideas what to look for beyond this?

When it runs, I see my lat/lon, pin title, and subtitle filled in.

Heres my code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *) theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];

    MKPointAnnotation *pt = (MKPointAnnotation *)annotation;

    NSString *PINNAME = pt.title;
    CLLocationDegrees lat = pt.coordinate.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees lon = pt.coordinate.longitude;
    [Log log:TINFO :@"lat/lon %f - %f", lat, lon];
    [Log log:TINFO :@"pin title userid = %@", pt.title];
    [Log log:TINFO :@"subtitle: %@", pt.subtitle];

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: PINNAME];

    if(pinView == nil)
    {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:PINNAME];
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pinView;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the call to `removeAnnotations` from `viewForAnnotation`, because having it there will remove any annotations that you may have been in the process of displaying on the map. If your intent was to remove old annotations before adding new one, you should do that before you call `addAnnotation`, not in `viewForAnnotation`.

Unrelated to your current issue:

1. And even if you really wanted to remove all the annotations, if it's possible that you might (at some point) have the `MKUserLocation` on your map, I'd suggest only removing the annotations where the annotation class is not `MKUserLocation`. I've noticed weird behavior when I accidentally removed the `MKUserLocation` from the array of `annotations`.
2. As an aside, I might suggest using `theMapView` parameter, rather than `self.mapView`. You don't want to risk problems stemming from a messed up `IBOutlet`. No need to reference the `self.mapView` when `theMapView` was passed as a parameter.
3. You're conceivably using a unique `identifier` for each `MKAnnotationView`. There's nothing that I see in this code that necessitates that, and you lose much of the efficiencies gained by using dequeued annotations. Use the same `identifier` string for all annotation views of a particular kind (and you only appear to have one type of annotation).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Rob.  Good stuff.  I think Im misunderstanding unique identifiers in this case.  If you use lets say 'thePin' as the identifier, and you place many of them, how does 'viewForAnnotation' know which pin to dequeue?  I know tableview's work this way too, so now Im curious.

Comment: @Tim It dequeues whatever pins have scrolled out of view. It's analogous to the cell identifier for a `UITableViewCell`. One identifier for all similar-looking annotations.

Comment: It seems I had a removeAnnotations in a bad spot that didnt bite me until now.  Im also finding that when I call [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];  and then add new annotations, both sets of annotations are still on the map.  Very odd.

Comment: After a while of digging online, I found that to actually remove the annotations from the map you (apparently) need to give mapView.annotations (in this case) a new pointer to the array of pins (which may just be nil to remove the old ones).  Not obvious.  Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    //UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ttile" message:@"working" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    //[alert show];
    MKAnnotationView *view = nil;
    if(annotation != mv.userLocation) {
        // if it's NOT the user's current location pin, create the annotation
        Park *parkAnnotation = (Park*)annotation;
        // Look for an existing view to reuse
        view = [mv dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"parkAnnotation"];
        // If an existing view is not found, create a new one
        if(view == nil) {
            view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:(id) parkAnnotation
                                                   reuseIdentifier:@"parkAnnotation"];
        }

        // Now we have a view for the annotation, so let's set some properties
        [(MKPinAnnotationView *)view setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorRed];
        [(MKPinAnnotationView *)view setAnimatesDrop:YES];
        [view setCanShowCallout:YES];

        // Now create buttons for the annotation view
        // The 'tag' properties are set so that we can identify which button was tapped later
        UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
        leftButton.tag = 0;
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        rightButton.tag = 1;

        // Add buttons to annotation view
        [view setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:leftButton];
        [view setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];
    }

    // send this annotation view back to MKMapView so it can add it to the pin
    return view;
}
```